# C Double Free Problem

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free

I'm running into a double free, and I can't see where it's happening. The objective of the following code is to delete Person nodes from a Linked List.

```
typedef struct person {
    char *first ;
    char *last ;
    char *location ;
    struct person *next_person ;
} person ;

struct person_list {
    int num_persons ;
    person *first_person ;
} person_list ;

extern struct person_list person_list ;

void free_person(person *person) {
    free(person->first);
    person->first = NULL;

    free(person->last);
    person->last = NULL;

    free(person->location);
    person->location = NULL;

    free(person);
    person = NULL;
}

...

    if (person_list.num_persons > 0) {
        while (person_list.num_persons > 0) {
            //Iterate to the end of the chain.
            cur_person = person_list.first_person;

            while (cur_person->next_person != NULL) {
                cur_person = cur_person->next_person;
            }

            free_person(cur_person);
            person_list.num_persons--;
        }
    }

...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you free the person, you do not set the previous person's `next_person` pointer to `NULL`. Therefore, it points to freed memory, and that's why you are double freeing.

You would need to keep track of the person coming just before the one you want to free, and set its `next_person` pointer to `NULL`.

Another more efficient way to write your loop would be the following, which is not subject to the same error:

```
    // Grab the first person
    cur_person = person_list.first_person;

    // Make sure there is someone to free
    while (cur_person != NULL) {
        // Keep track of who to free next
        nxt_person = cur_person->next_person;

        free_person(cur_person);

        // Get the next person in line
        cur_person = nxt_person;
    }

    // Didn't we just remove them all? Yes, we did.
    person_list.num_persons = 0;
    // Let's not forget to set that we have no one left
    person_list.first_person = NULL;
```

Comment: But free_person sets that person to NULL. Why doesn't that work?

Comment: As pmg wrote, it only sets the local copy inside the function. You would need to set it to NULL outside the function, or pass a reference (which is a C++ feature, not C).

Comment: I'm still getting a double delete error in my code. Could it be due to corruption?

Comment: Make sure in `free_person` that all those things you are freeing are not `NULL`. Check if `person` is NULL, then check if `person->first` is NULL before freeing it, and so on. Maybe you never allocated `person->first` and al in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
void free_person(person *person) {
    /* ... */
    free(person);
    person = NULL;
}
```

This only sets the local `person` to NULL; there is no change to the person on the calling routine.

Answer (score 1):

In the `free_person` function the assignments to `NULL` are not really necessary because you are freeing the containing structure as well. Otherwise it would be necessary to prevent having a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Also, `person = NULL` only assigns the local parameter of the function which is lost right after its return.